# Node.js Q ninvoke multiple arguments

Tags: node.js, promise, q

How would one pass multiple arguments into Q ninvoke?

For example:

```
exports.getBalance = function () {
    return Q.ninvoke(library, 'method', **[Arguments]**);
}
```

At the moment I have

```
return Q.ninvoke(library, 'method', '*', 6);
```

Where arguments is an array or list of arguments?

I'd like to reuse my ninvoke call, but sometimes methods take one or more parameters.

Thanks.

Richard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.nfpost` which works like  `ninvoke` only with an arguments array instead of variable arguments:

```
 Q.ninvoke(library, 'method', myArgumentsArray);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qnpostobject-methodname-args).